# Find $a$, $b$ for $z = \frac{1}{(a + ib)^3}$ to be on negative real axis

Tags: complex-numbers

> For what values of $a$ and $b$ does
>   \begin{equation}
> z = \frac{1}{(a + ib)^3}
> \end{equation}
>   lie on the negative real axis. Hence, or otherwise, find an expression in terms of $a$ only for $\lvert z \rvert$ when $\operatorname{arg}(z) = - \pi$.

How would I approach this question?

Comment: Hello, I see you are new to this site. Use MathJax to format your questions, not images. Also, we are not here to solve your homework! You should show us that you tried solving the problem, and we will be glad to help you out, or at least point you to a right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For $z$ to lie on the negative real axis, we have 
$$z = \frac{1}{(a + ib)^3}=-r=re^{i(1+2n)\pi}$$

where $r>0$. Rearrange to get

$$a+bi= \frac1{\sqrt[3]r} e^{-i\frac{(1+2n)\pi}3}
=\frac1{\sqrt[3]r} \left( \cos\frac{1+2n}3\pi - i\sin\frac{1+2n}3\pi \right)
$$

with $n=0,1,2$. Then,

$$a= \frac1{\sqrt[3]r} \cos\frac{1+2n}3\pi,\>\>\>\>\>
b= -\frac1{\sqrt[3]r} \sin\frac{1+2n}3\pi$$

Evalute at $n=0,1,2$ to obtain the values for $(a,b)$

$$(a.b)=( -c,0),\>(c,\pm\sqrt3c)$$

where $c$ represents any positive real number.